# Eclipse Dark Theme on Linux Mint Cinammon

Tags: eclipse, themes

I'm struggling to run any plugin that makes Eclipse IDE more "dark". I tested both:

1. http://rogerdudler.github.io/eclipse-ui-themes/
2. https://raw.github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/

But the problem is that under Cinnamon buttons background doesn't change. But for instance tabs from tabbed pane does. Here you have screenshot how it looks like
[image]

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I see the same thing (Linux Mint 16, Eclipse 4.3.2)

Comment: @MartinWallgren Unfortunately I do not. But it works for me under Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity out of box. So I believe this glitch is more user interface (Gnome, KDE, etc) dependent than distro it self. Have you try Cinnamon 2.0 UI? Also one minute ago I found this link maybe it will help somehow: https://github.com/jinmingjian/eclipse.themes.darker/issues/13
any way I drop attemps to fix that.

Comment: @MartinWallgren I also find the following: http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/11/dark-eclipse-ships-with-eclipse-luna/
It's still milestone, but dark theme will be included out of box in eclipse in new version, so I believe - patience is the key...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some mint themes come with controls.

In Linuxmint 17:

- install cinammon theme **delorean-dark** or **D-dark_smaragd** (I prefer the first one)
- quit and restart cinnamon-settings
- now you should be able to select **delorean-dark** or **D-dark_smaragd** for controls on other-settings tab

Eclipse is fine now, but synaptic looks theird after that (gnome 3 fallback theme):

- themes are installed to ~/.themes - so I copied them to /root/.themes

Comment: Where is "other-settings tab"? You mean eclipse settings or system? Please explain. Thanks

Comment: @Sonique He meant system settings. Eclipse is build on SWT which use native GTK controls (we still talking about XFCE). Therefore changing system theme changes Eclipse as well. But be sure to fully restart Eclipse process cause not all controls refresh upon theme change dynamically.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as best since any solution that tries override GTK settings basically have glitches. Eclipse is old, build on SWT and any "Theme" solution from IDE itself sux. Instead of fighting it either change to IntelliJ or change system theme. That's my advice after hours spend.